# Object as jQuery.fn prototype?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I define prototype like this

```
jQuery.fn.myFunc = function() {
    console.log(this);
}
```

and call it like this:

```
$('div').myFunc();
```

`this` inside of `myFunc` will refer to jQuery object selection.

Now if I don't want to pollute `.fn` with multiple attached functions, can I do something like

```
jQuery.fn.myPlugin =  {

    myFunc1: function() {

    },

    myFunc2: function() {

    }       

}
```

If I call it `$('div').myPlugin.myFunc1();` - how do I get reference to selected objects inside of `myFunc1`? Or is there a different, better approach?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extremely Simple jQuery Plugin Tutorial?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10638948/extremely-simple-jquery-plugin-tutorial)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. can't do it that way. Instead, define it as a function, then add properties to that function.

```
jQuery.fn.myPlugin = function() {
    console.log(this);
};

jQuery.fn.myPlugin.myFunc1 = function() {

};

jQuery.fn.myPlugin.myFunc2 = function() {

};
```

note that myFunc1 and myFunc2 still wont' have access to the selected element, therefore it's relatively useless to define them this way other than the fact that they can be easily overridden by other developers (which is a good thing)

The normal way of having additional methods within your plugin is to have your plugin method accept a parameter that can eitehr be an object to init the plugin, or a string to execute a target method on the element. for example, `$("somediv").myPlugin("myFunc1")`

Comment: So if I understood correctly, only "root" function assigned directly to `.fn.name` will have access to selected elements. There is no way to define several functions under common "namespace" I guess, that would have this ability?

Comment: I recall seeing some widget framework that someone put together a while back that allowed for it, but it was very complex and i haven't been able to find it since and don't know of any plugins that actually used it. Therefore, yes, there is a way to do it, i just don't know it and can't point you in the direction of finding it. I wouldn't suggest trying to do it that way because that way of using a plugin is so rare that it'd be easier on your users to use a more common interface.

Comment: Beautiful. I liked `$("somediv").myPlugin("myFunc1")` approach.

Answer (score 0):

work if you create a object before.

Like this:

```
 <script>
    jQuery.fn.myPlugin = {};

    jQuery.fn.myPlugin =  {

        myFunc1: function() {
            console.log(this);
        },

        myFunc2: function() {
            alert(this);
        }       

    };
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('div').myPlugin.myFunc1();
        $('div').myPlugin.myFunc2();
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Nope, `this`still returns `myPlugin` object itself

Answer (score 0):

The [jQuery plugin tutorial](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/) suggests this:

```
(function( $ ) {

    $.fn.popup = function( action ) {

        if ( action === "open") {
            // Open popup code.
        }

        if ( action === "close" ) {
            // Close popup code.
        }

    };

}( jQuery ));
```

I suppose this would be another alternative:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.myPlugin = function (action) {
        var functions = {
            open: function () {
                console.log('open: ', this);
            },
            close: function () {
                console.log('close:', this);
            }
        }

        if (action && functions[action]) {
            functions[action].call(this)
        } else {
            console.log('no function', this);
        }

        return this;
    };
}(jQuery));

$('#theDiv')
    .myPlugin()
    .myPlugin('open')
    .myPlugin('close');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/faJAk/

Answer (score 0):

Another possible approach is to use [`defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty):

```
(function($) {

    var myPlugin = {
        foo: function() {
            console.log(this)
        }
    }

    Object.defineProperty($.fn, "myPlugin", {
        get : function() { return $.extend({}, this, myPlugin) }
    });

})(jQuery);
```

Now `$(...).myPlugin.foo` should resolve `this` correctly:

```
$(function() {
    $("body").myPlugin.foo(); // logs "body"
})
```

Comment: Does it have to be called within `$(function(){ })` ?

Comment: @YuriyGalanter: if you mean `(function($)..)(jQuery)` - no, but this is considered good practice and useful when your plugin has its own local variables and functions.